# Find linux files with similar names but having different date

Tags: linux, bash

I have some files named like this:

```
aaa-bbb-xxx.ext
aaa-bbb-yyy.ext2
aaa-bbb-zzz.ext3
```

Some of them are of the same date - then I'm not interested in them. I'd like to find only those files which dates (basically, day of editing) differs. How do I find them? Thank you.

**Edit: I forgot to mention - all of files are in the same directory, so there is no need to look up for them on the HDD; the only problem is to make a recognition in the following manner:**

**1. get 3 files matching the pattern**

**2. check their dates (day basically) of editing**

**3. if dates are different, list these files; if the same, ignore**

**4. continue until all files are checked in the directory**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Differs from what? For your sample input files, show the modification date and then show what output you want.

Comment: "similar names" -- do you have some algorithm to group files according to their names being "close enough"? Is `aaa-bbc-uuu.ext` a similar name?

Comment: I put example pattern of 'similar' names - I need to iterate over all of the similar names (i.e. of same pattern) - typically 3 of the same group, and then check if at least one of them has a different date than the others of those.

Answer (score 0):

Linux command "Locate"
may help you.

Comment: There is no much difference between find and locate, in fact. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60205/locate-vs-find-usage-pros-and-cons-of-each-other